# How to use Appengine Gradle Plugin with standard environment

Tags: google-app-engine, gradle, appengine-gradle-plugin

After putting it off for a long time, I am finally updating from the [gradle-appengine-plugin](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-plugin) to the [app-gradle-plugin](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/app-gradle-plugin).  Although the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/gradle)[[1](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/gradle-reference)] calls for using an appengine-web file to configure the app, the plugin looks for an [app.yaml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/reference/app-yaml) configuration, which seems to be specific to the flexible environment.  Does anyone have tips on either getting the plugin to use the appengine-web configuration, or configuring app.yaml for the standard environment?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the problem was that the plugin does not use the `appEngineDirectory` setting when looking for `appengine-web.xml`.  Instead, it looks for a `app.yaml` file in that directory, and returns an error when it is not found (even if `appengine-web.yaml` is there).  If the `appengine-web.xml` file is in the standard `WEB-INF` folder, it works as expected.

I'll update if I can figure out how to use a custom directory for `appengine-web.xml`.

Comment: Issue to track: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/app-gradle-plugin/issues/358

Comment: The location of `appengine-web.xml` is not configurable. The file must be under `WEB-INF` and included as part of the WAR archive. Check https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/app-gradle-plugin/issues/358] for the details.